# Interchange character in String

Tags: java, string, character

I have a string.

```
String word = "Football";
```

I need to place the first character of the string to the very end of the string. Here is my solution.

```
public class charToString{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String testString = "Football";
        char[] stringToCharArray = testString.toCharArray();

        for(int i=0;i<(stringToCharArray.length-1);i++){
            char temp = stringToCharArray[i];
            stringToCharArray[i]= stringToCharArray[i+1];
            stringToCharArray[i+1] = temp;

        }//end of for

        String resulT = new String(stringToCharArray); //result with desired output
        System.out.println(resulT);
    }// end of main
}
```

Is this an efficient way to complete my task? Or can you suggest me a more efficient way to do this?

Comment: it can be more easy. `String str2 = testString.substring(1) + testString.substring(0,1)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more efficient solution than substring and concatenation would be to use a `StringBuilder`:

```
String result =
    new StringBuilder(word.length())
        .append(word, 1, word.length())
        .append(word, 0, 1) // or .append(word.charAt(0))
        .toString();
```

This simply avoids creating the substrings from `word`.

Answer (score 3):

Your solution using substring is fine, but here is an alternative solution using regex:

```
String word = "Football";
String result = word.replaceAll("^(.)(.*)$", "$2$1");
System.out.println(result);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use substrings:

```
testString.substring(1) + testString.substring(0, 1)
```

Comment: it return `ootballF` for me!

Comment: @NicholasK: I think you made a mistake: the above should work (tested with `jshell`).

Answer (score 1):

Why not just

```
word = word.substring(1, word.length()) + word.charAt(0);
```

EDIT :

Or just use `substring` without the length.

```
word = word.substring(1) + word.charAt(0);
```